# How to print Django Ajax return as Template Data?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I want to print `Products` data returned by following views on template. When I check the context its printing the correct data but when I try to print data in template it shows nothing. I checked Networks inside browser console, data is called there but I dont know why its not printing to views

Template

```
 {% for product in products%}
                    {{product.name}}
                    {%endfor%}
```

My Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var compare = localStorage.getItem("comparisionItems");
    var compareObj = JSON.parse(compare);
    
    
    
    console.log(compareObj)
    
   
      
    $.ajax({
      url: './compare',
      type: "POST",
      data: compare,
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
      dataType: "json",
      contentType : "application/json",
      processData: "false",
      success: function (data) {
        location.reload();
          
       },
      
    });
});
```

Views.py

```
def compare(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":             
        data = json.loads(request.body)     
        compare_ids = data['itemIds']      
        products = Products.objects.filter(id__in=compare_ids)   
        print(products)   
        context={'products':products}
        return render(request,'./compare.html', context)
    else:
     return render(request,'./compare.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

### QuerySets are lazy!

When you call print() function or log() function in browser console,  products queryset will evaluate immediately

You  can use all() so it evaluate in your template:

`products = Products.objects.filter(id__in=compare_ids).all()`

Also take a look at this [documentions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

---

#### Server-side :

because you don't hit database, so use GET method:

in views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET

@required_GET
def compare(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') =='XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax:             
        compare_ids = request.GET.get('itemIds')          
        products = Products.objects.filter(id__in=compare_ids).all()     
        context={'products':products}
        return render(request,'./compare.html', context)
    else:
     return render(request,'./compare.html')
```

---

### Client-side:

you should replace html nor reload

```
$.ajax({
      url: './compare',
      type: 'GET',
      data: compare,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('your_list_selector').html(data);
       },
      
    });
```

Comment: I checked Networks inside browser console, data is called there and console printed correctly so thats not the issue here.

Comment: Oh, i think you should use other success function than reload because it reset your template, also you dont need to use post method if you dont hit database, it is better that you use get method

Comment: It hits the database, because I need to print database object which has id equals to localstorage item id. 

I am getting data but its printing only on network console, what I assume is when page loads it gets loaded with get request and Ajax is passed via post. Now that post data is not rectifying.

Comment: i updated my answer, do you try it?do you remove location.reload ?

Comment: my english is bad, i means that you are reading data from database and not writing it , so you dont need POST method

Comment: it would be better if you could update your answer for the answer from your side